# entry appears per index in at least two different months within a year

Tags: python, pandas

index   date(dd.mm.yy)

A       1.1.20
A       1.2.20
B       1.1.20
B       5.5.21 
C       1.1.20
C       10.1.20
D       1.1.20 
D       10.1.20
D       10.5.20

I want to see if an entry appears per index in at least two different months **within a year**

So for index A ,D the answer is True and for B, C is False expected output:

A       True
B       False 
C       False
D       True

I can easliy see if it appears in at least two different months (or years) by using Grouper

```
df.groupby([index, pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date]).agg('count')
```

and see if count > 0

but how can i easily check both conditions apply?

I tried to create my own agg function or use the Grouper.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/how-to-count-occurrences-of-values-within-specific-range-by-row/29684 Possibly useful

Answer (score 0):

If we want shape of the dataframe same as before:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)

def resampled_data(freq):
    return df.groupby(['index', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq=freq)]).index.transform('count')

yg = resampled_data('Y')
mg = resampled_data('M')

df['bool'] = ((yg >= 2) & (mg != 2)) | ((yg >= 3) & (mg >=2))
```

**Output**

```
    index   date    bool
0   A   2020-01-01  True
1   A   2020-02-01  True
2   B   2020-01-01  False
3   B   2021-05-05  False
4   C   2020-01-01  False
5   C   2020-01-10  False
6   D   2020-01-01  True
7   D   2020-01-10  True
8   D   2020-05-10  True
```

Comment: but then if the two entires appeared in the same month it's a wrong true. i'll edit the example

Comment: Can you please provide expected output

Comment: done (the duplications don't really matter)

Comment: great, added the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_per_month = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.groupby([index, df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month]).groups.keys())
df_max_entries_in_a_year = df_per_month.groupby([0,1]).agg('count').reset_index().groupby([0])[2].agg('max')
```